# How to install WhatsApp on iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore, install, whatsapp.app

How can I install WhatsApp on iPad mini (cellular)? It's not jailbroken and I am using iOS 7 but I cant install WhatsApp on it.

Comment: Which steps have you tried, what was the result/error message?

Comment: I searched the app in app store but when i try to install it says this app does not support your device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhatsApp Messenger is currently not optimised for iPad, and therefore you will need to search for iPhone apps in the App Store search using the filter at the top.

Comment: Yeah thank you. is there any other way by which if i can able to install it?

Comment: @dking You can download the app in iTunes and install it on sync.

Answer (score 0):

There is one that I would recommend, it covers almost all features from WhatsApp Web and it is quite fast on iPad: [iPad Messenger for WhatsApp - Free](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1157181090?pt=117865237&ct=WhatsAppiPadFree&mt=8)

It's very sad that WhatsApp does not offer a client for iPad and I've been trying a lot of ways to get it working on iPad without jailbreaking. The web version is for sure the most secure and reliable way to use it on iPad. It is actually pain less to use. The most of the apps on the App Store are not reliable at all because of the excessive ads showing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  When posting your answer, it's advisable to post it first and **then** post your commentary, if commentary is necessary.  This makes it easier for the reader to find the actual answer.  You might want to review the section [Answering](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/answering) in our [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help).